# Thymeleaf Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Tags: javascript, thymeleaf

I'm trying to pass an onclick event to Javascript using Thymeleaf but getting "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list".

```
      <li th:onclick="'radar(' + ${radar} + ', ' + ${radarList} + ');'" th:each="radar : ${radarList}" th:id="${radar.index}">
          <button class="button button_module" th:id="${radar.index}">
              <img th:src="@{/images/icon_module_radar.png}" /><br />
              <span th:text="${radar.name}"/>
          </button>
      </li>


function radar(id, list)
{
    for (var i in list)
    {
        document.getElementById(list[i]['index']).className = "button button_module";
    }
    document.getElementById(id['index']).className = "button button_module_selected";

    setRadarStats(id);
}
```

I think ${radarList} is passing object to list as intended, but I can't see for sure because I'm getting an error.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you replace this line of code

```
th:onclick="'radar(' + ${radar} + ', ' + ${radarList} + ');'"
```

with

```
<li th:onclick="'javascript:radar(\'' + ${radar} +'\',\''+ ${radarList} +  '\');'"
```

and let me know if this worked for you

Comment: Well I wanted to avoid using that as that'll parse ${radarList} into string and not object. But I guess there's no other way :(